# Converting tree representing math expression to a string without redundant parentheses

Tags: java, c#, .net, algorithm, visitor-pattern

I want to convert **a tree** that represents a **math expression** into the actual math expression (a string like `"a+b/c"`)

The tree representation is the simplest you could imagine:

`A+B/C` would be this tree:

```
OperationNode(+, A, OperationNode(/, B, C))
```

And `(A+B)/C` would be this tree:

```
OperationNode(/, OperationNode(+, A, B), C)
```

In order to convert the tree into the string, I'm using the Visitor pattern. The problem comes with parentheses.

My current Visitor implementation ALWAYS adds parentheses to the nodes, so every tree I generate turns into a string like this:

(((A+B)+C)+D)

**Notice the redundant parentheses.**

So the question is: how could I make my Visitor generate the string with no redundant parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NelFeal wrote while walking the tree you just need to check if precedence of suboperation less than a precedence of the current operation.

I implemented visitor pattern for you, hope it helps.

```
enum Operation
{
    Add,
    Multiply,
    Power,
    UnaryMinus,
    None,
}

static class OperationExtensions
{
    public static string ToFriendlyString(this Operation me)
    {
        switch (me)
        {
            case Operation.None:
                return "";
            case Operation.Add:
                return "+";
            case Operation.Multiply:
                return "*";
            case Operation.Power:
                return "^";
            case Operation.UnaryMinus:
                return "-";
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
}

class OperationNode
{
    public Operation Op;
    public OperationNode(Operation op)
    {
        Op = op;
    }
}

interface IVisitor
{
    void Visit(OperationNodeLeaf node);
    void Visit(OperationNode1 node);
    void Visit(OperationNode2 node);
}

sealed class Visitor : IVisitor
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    private void Enclose(OperationNode subNode, Operation op)
    {
        if (subNode.Op < op)
        {
            Text = Text + "(";
            Visit((dynamic)subNode);
            Text = Text + ")";
        }
        else
        {
            Visit((dynamic)subNode);
        }
    }

    public void Visit(OperationNodeLeaf node)
    {
        Text = Text + node.Op.ToFriendlyString();
        Text = Text + node.Value.ToString();
    }

    public void Visit(OperationNode1 node)
    {
        Text = Text + node.Op.ToFriendlyString();
        Enclose(node.SubNode, node.Op);
    }

    public void Visit(OperationNode2 node)
    {
        Enclose(node.LeftSubNode, node.Op);
        Text = Text + node.Op.ToFriendlyString();
        Enclose(node.RightSubNode, node.Op);
    }
}

class OperationNodeLeaf : OperationNode
{
    public int Value;
    public OperationNodeLeaf(int v, Operation op = Operation.None) : base(op)
    {
        Value = v;
    }
    void Accept(IVisitor v)
    {
        v.Visit(this);
    }
}

class OperationNode1 : OperationNode
{
    public OperationNode SubNode;
    public OperationNode1(OperationNode sn, Operation op) : base(op)
    {
        SubNode = sn;
    }
    void Accept(IVisitor v)
    {
        v.Visit(this);
    }
}

class OperationNode2 : OperationNode
{
    public OperationNode LeftSubNode;
    public OperationNode RightSubNode;
    public OperationNode2(OperationNode lsn, OperationNode rsn, Operation op) : base(op)
    {
        LeftSubNode = lsn;
        RightSubNode = rsn;
    }
    void Accept(IVisitor v)
    {
        v.Visit(this);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tree = 
            new OperationNode2(
                new OperationNode2(
                    new OperationNode2(new OperationNodeLeaf(5), new OperationNodeLeaf(6), Operation.Add),
                    new OperationNode2(new OperationNodeLeaf(5), new OperationNodeLeaf(6), Operation.Multiply),
                    Operation.Power
                    ),
                new OperationNode2(
                    new OperationNode2(new OperationNodeLeaf(1), new OperationNodeLeaf(2), Operation.Multiply),
                    new OperationNode1(new OperationNodeLeaf(7, Operation.None), Operation.UnaryMinus),
                    Operation.Add
                    ),
                Operation.Multiply
                );
        var visitor = new Visitor();
        visitor.Visit(tree);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(visitor.Text);
    }
}
```

> (5+6)^(5*6)*(1*2+-7)

Comment: Thanks great! and it works! But the implementation of Visitor is not the standard I have seen. Typically, the Visit method is void. How would that affect to the implementation?

Comment: @SuperJMN I've updated it according to proper visitor pattern and added new operation to test it.

Comment: Big thanks, my friend! You've make me understand the logic under the problem and I finally got unstuck. I have uploaded the code of my own visitor here, if you want to check for curiosity: https://github.com/SuperJMN/Simple-Formula-Parser/blob/master/FormulaParser/ExpressionFormatter.cs I'm creating a simple formular parser.

Comment: My pleasure:) And i glad you've used `StringBuilder`, i'm rather new to C#, so i used `string` just to be faster.

Comment: Feel free to ask anything about C#. Catch me at GitHub! Thanks, sincerely.

Answer (score 1):

You need a operator precedence table. Simply assign precedence values to every operator you support (and maybe to the topmost no-op that gives you the outermost pair of parentheses). Then, for each operation node, if its operation has a higher precedence than the parent node operation, you don't need parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, but do you think you could post some sample? Maybe a simple Visitor? I hope it's not asking for too much :) I'm still not sure if I understand you well.

Comment: Not in Java, C# or .NET. Maybe if you post your sample, I can try modifying it.